# How can I replace the characters?

Tags: c++, c

Given a string `"abc{efg}dgb"`, I would like to perform a substitution on the characters between the braces. This is what I'm currently trying. But it needs to `memcpy` 3 times. Can that be improved?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void replace(char *newWord,char *a,char *b)
{
  char *p;
  char *q;
  int offset = 0;
  int pos = 0;
  int len_b = strlen(b);
  p= strchr(a,'{');
  offset = p -a;
  memcpy(newWord,a,offset);
  offset += pos;
  memcpy(newWord+offset,b,len_b);
  offset += len_b;
  q = strchr(a,'}');
  memcpy(newWord+offset,q+1,strlen(q+1));
}


int main()
{
  char *a = "abc{acd}efg";
  char *b = "new";
  char *q;
  char newWord[1024]="";

  replace(newWord,a,b);

  printf("%s",newWord);
}
```

Now newWord is "abcnewefg"

Comment: benchmark your program before imagining that a precise call is slow. Also, C and C++ are different languages. Choose one! (If you choose C++, be sure to use [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) if available).

Comment: The solution for C and C++ will be different. Pick one.

Comment: i have change the qustion,will will I can post again?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to get you on the right foot in C++

1. Place your string in a `std::string`
2. Using [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) find "{"
3. Using [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) again, find "}" that goes after the "{" you found in step 2
4. Use [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) to remove the chars using the information you got from step 2 and step 3

Once you have that going, you can run it to see if the speed is efficient for what you need and then you can optimize based on what the bottle neck is.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency can refer to ease of coding, cost to maintain, or speed of execution. Usually you want to strike a balance between the 3.

Because you explicitly mention string, I assume you refer to C++, not C.

In a current C++ environment, replacing "something" in a string can easily be done with string::replace, or with regular expressions (a topic for itself).

If you want something that is harder to maintain but potentially faster, you can iterate over the string and insert or delete characters as necessary.